# Contents from API not being fully displayed

Tags: javascript, api

The code is being fetched but it is not being fully displayed, as in some parts are missing

https://github.com/KushRohra/GFG_Codes/blob/master/School/Leap%20year.cpp

You can see the code here and the one being displayed below.
However full code is being displayed in the console. dont know whats the problem

```
async function call() {
        let url = "https://api.github.com/repos/KushRohra/GFG_Codes/contents/School/Leap year.cpp";
        let response = await fetch(url);
        console.log(data);
        s = atob(data.content);
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = s.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
      }
      call();
```

```
<div id="code"></div>
```

Comment: console.log(data)? u didnt declare data at all

Answer (score -1):

Heres how your code should look like:

```js
async function call() {
            let url = "https://api.github.com/repos/KushRohra/GFG_Codes/contents/School/Leap year.cpp";
            let response = await fetch(url);
            let data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            let s = window.atob(data.content);
            document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = s.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
        }
        call();
```

1. You didn't declare data variable.
2. you didn't asked for a response to fetch body(response data) as a JSON() nor TEXT()
3. for atob function you better explicitly say window.atob() instead of atob()